# XCTest self measureBlock modification?

Tags: xcode, xctest

It appears that XCtest "self measureBlock" is limited to milliseconds and 10 runs of the test code. Are there any ways to modify the behavior of measureBlock for more runs and/or nano or microsecond accuracy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR

Apple provides a way to modify the behavior of `measureBlock:` by providing extra string constants but they don't support any string constants other than the default.

### Long explanation

`measureBlock` calls the following function

```
- (void)measureMetrics:(NSArray *)metrics automaticallyStartMeasuring:(BOOL)automaticallyStartMeasuring withBlock:(void (^)(void))block;
```

//The implementation looks something like this (I can't say 100% but i'm pretty sure):

```
- (void)measureBlock:(void (^)(void))block {
    NSArray<NSString *> *metrics = [[self class] defaultPerformanceMetrics];
    [self measureMetrics:metrics automaticallyStartMeasure:YES withBlock:block];
}
```

`defaultPerformanceMetrics` is a class function that returns an array of strings.

From the Xcode source

> "Subclasses can override this to change the behavior of
> `-measureBlock:`"

---

Lovely, that sounds promising; we have customization behavior right? Well, they don't give you any strings to return. The default is `XCTPerformanceMetric_WallClockTime ("com.apple.XCTPerformanceMetric_WallClockTime")`

It turns out there aren't any string constants to return besides that one.
See the slides for WWDC 2014 Session 414 Testing in Xcode 6 ([link](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB8QFjAAahUKEwjWg97H8d7HAhVK1YAKHSBCDl4&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdevstreaming.apple.com%2Fvideos%2Fwwdc%2F2014%2F414xx4l5du0f408%2F414%2F414_testing_in_xcode_6.pdf%3Fdl%3D1&usg=AFQjCNGxr7XUxPjFI1K06Wxp2pJbdoEmKA&sig2=aUBTx9IMV2-urHLcbDRU9g)).

I quote from page 158:

> Currently supports one metric: XCTPerformanceMetric_WallClockTime

Nothing else has been added in Xcode 7 so it seems you're out of luck trying to modify `measureBlock`, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I've never found `measureBlock:` very useful.  Check out `Tidbits.xcodeproj/TidbitsTestBase/TBTestHelpers/comparePerformance` https://github.com/tipbit/tidbits if you'd like to look at an alternative.